# Transfer file from SFTP server to the local system using Java

Tags: java, list, sftp, jsch

I am using the JSch library.

I need three methods:

- `void delete()` --- to delete the file with the given name
- `void copy()`   --- to copy the file with the given name into the local system
- `list copyndelete()` --- to copy the file and to delete the  file in the remote system ... and also return the name of the file deleted into the list.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [Apache FTPSClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jcraft . Its an Open source Project

Comment: -1. JCraft is the name of the company which produces the JSch library (and other products, too). JSch was already mentioned in the question, so nothing new here.

Answer (score 0):

The [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library contains the [ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) class. This class has (between others) also methods to

- copy remote files to local ones (all the `get` methods)
- delete remote files (the `rm` method, or `rmdir` to delete empty directories)
- list remote files (`ls`)

All your requirements can be fulfilled from combinations of these methods.